# Filtering datas in mongodb using specific date range

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime

[data snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru8uO.png)

Hi,
I have a datas like this in the database. I need to query the datas between start and end of the specific month.
I have used python and write the code as below,

```
            start_of_month = datetime.datetime(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0)
            last_day_number = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
            last_of_month = datetime.datetime(year, month, last_day_number)

           for finding query => {"date": {"$gte": start_of_month, "$lt": end_of_month}}
```

This code is not working properly. could you help me out?

Comment: look like your date is in string.Is that so?

Comment: yes, the date is in string format

Answer (score 0):

if the date as i can see in picture is in string formate then you can use this sample code.

```
import datetime
import calendar

year = 2023  # Replace with your desired year
month = 10   # Replace with your desired month

start_of_month = datetime.datetime(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0)
last_day_number = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
end_of_month = datetime(year, month, last_day_number, 23, 59, 59)

query = {
    "date": {
        "$gte": start_of_month.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        "$lt": end_of_month.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. I will try it out and let you know :)

Comment: Its working perfectly. thanks for your help buddy